How to set color of row in TStringGrid?
I have a challenge.
There is a list in a TStringGrid. Above this list is a TLabeledEdit field. When I type some value into this Edit and then press a button, I scan the list and compare this value with every value in one column of the grid. If I find it, I need to color the background of this row.
My code:
val := LabeledEdit2.Text;
for i := 1 to StringGrid1.RowCount do
begin
  if StringGrid1.Cells[4, i] = val then
  begin
  end
  else
  begin
    ShowMessage('Wrong value');
  end;
end;

How can I to do this?

Related/dupe: Setting background color of selected row on TStringGrid. You need to use the TStringGrid.OnDrawCell event to do any custom coloring of the cells. As such, you will have to draw every cell yourself. If needed, you can use the TStringGrid.Objects property to keep track of any custom data you want on a per-cell basis, and then use that data inside your event handler.

This question is similar to: Setting background color of selected row on TStringGrid. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

TStringGrid has no properties for setting row or cell colors, so the only way to accomplish this is by drawing the cells yourself, using the OnDrawCell event.
It could look something like this:
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; 
  ACol, ARow: Integer; 
  Rect: TRect; 
  State: TGridDrawState);
var
  IsMatchingRow: Boolean;
  CellText: string;
begin
  IsMatchingRow := (StringGrid1.Cells[4, ARow] = LabeledEdit2.Text);

  if IsMatchingRow then
    StringGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clYellow
  else
    StringGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;

  CellText := StringGrid1.Cells[ACol, ARow];

  StringGrid1.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  StringGrid1.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + 2, Rect.Top + 2, CellText);
end;

And the code for the button would simply look like this, which forces a redraw:
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StringGrid1.Invalidate;
end;


It would be more efficient to move the text comparison into the Button handler. Let the Button scan the grid 1 time and save the index of the matching row before invalidating the grid, then have the OnDrawCell handler check that saved index while coloring cells. Don't do the text retrieval and comparison on every redraw. Remember the grid is going to redraw many times in its life as the parent window is redrawn many times. Drawing should be as simple as possible to avoid a sluggish UI

@RemyLebeau Probably in most realistic cases, indeed. Perhaps not if the string grid is very large (only the visible part would need drawing), or its contents changes and it's hard to put an event handler in that place. But otherwise, yes. Although in practice, I've seen much "worse" calculations in DrawCell and it works quite well, too.
